# Redis sentinel with multilevel replicas

Tags: redis, middleware, high-availability, redis-cluster, redis-sentinel

I am using **Sentinel** as a high availability solution for redis.

I have a problem.

In consideration of reducing the replication pressure of the master, our redis instances are multi-level, as follow: 
[image]
In the introduction of the [sentinel](https://redis.io/topics/sentinel), I found that can monitor multiple masters, so I import it and hope to work as follows: 
[image]
The second row of the replica belongs to the "master" logically too, so it also needs to be monitored.

Get the opposite of what one wants When the Sentinels **just started**, they had an election and independent many masters, actual master(role: master), not logic master.

**Q: So can sentinels do the monitoring mode in the figure above?**

My main configuration is as follows:

```
sentinel monitor top-master xxx.x.x.x 6379 2

sentinel monitor second-level-first xxx.x.x.x 6379 2

sentinel monitor second-level-second xxx.x.x.x 6379 2

sentinel monitor second-level-third xxx.x.x.x 6379 2
```

Answer (score 0):

IN BRIEF - NO

To answer the above you would want to drill down into what sentinel is doing.

- It is going to find out all the slaves it is connected to a master.
- it establishes a pub-sub with those nodes.
- when your actual master fails and another node becomes master this cannot be propagated.

Infact, to answer further more, can you please share the configuration of your slave nodes on level1? Infact this should have not been possible at all. I am just wondering how this worked.
If you can share the config files, will go through and update accordingly.